# SSRS Expression - Change Background Color BEFORE and AFTER a Value

Tags: reporting-services, expression, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I have a Matrix that displays Dealer Names, Franchise and City, with a Calculation for each product sold,  I have included GROUP AVERAGE as a Dealer Name.

[image]

The report displays a list of Dealers with ProductA value.
Once Ordered, GROUP AVERAGE appears in the middle of the list.
I want to colour all cells above the group average light green,
and all the cells below coral.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like below..

```
=IIF(
    Fields!Turnover.Value > 
        SUM(IIF(Fields!Branch.Value = "GROUP AVERAGE", Fields!Turnover.Value, 0), "DataSet1"),
        "LightGreen",
        "LightCoral"
        )
```

If basically reads, if the Turnover of the current context (the row) is greater than the sum of all turnover values where the branch = "group average" within the scope of the entire dataset, then green else red.

This gives the following output.

[image]

You could set the row visibility to check the branch name if you wanted to hide the actual average row.

Comment: Its Changing All Cells with values to green , GROUP AVERAGE to Red, and all cells that = 0 to Red. I would also like GROUP AVERAGE to remain white.

Comment: Show a sample of your data in the form it is returned from the dataset query, you can see by the example that I posted that this works based on the sample data in your question.